# What is the suggested way to instantiate a js.Object for API wrappers

Tags: scala, scala.js

For the following javascript API wrapper:

```
@JSName("React")
object React extends js.Object {
  def createClass(init: ReactClassInit): ReactClassBuilder = ???
}
```

What is the suggested what to instantiate the following trait

```
trait ReactClassInit extends js.Object {
  val render: js.ThisFunction0[js.Dynamic, js.Any]
}
```

Currently I am doing the following:

```
val * = js.Dynamic.literal
val init = *(render = new js.ThisFunction0[js.Dynamic, js.Any] {
  override def apply(thisArg: js.Dynamic): js.Any = {
    React.DOM.div(null, "Hello ", thisArg.props.name)
  }
}).asInstanceOf[ReactClassInit]
val HelloMessage = React.createClass(init)
```

What I don't like about this approach is that there is no type-safety
ensuring that ReactClassInit is instantiated properly.

(Here is all of the code to put things into a better context)

```
//Work in progress React wrapers
@JSName("React")
object React extends js.Object {
  def createClass(init: ReactClassInit): ReactClassBuilder = ???
  def renderComponent(cls: ReactClassInstance, mountNode: HTMLElement) = ???
  val DOM: ReactDOM = ???
}

trait ReactDOM extends js.Object {
  def div(huh: js.Any, something: js.String, propsOrWhat: js.Any) = ???
}

trait ReactClassInstance extends js.Object

trait ReactClassBuilder extends js.Object {
  def apply(args: js.Object): ReactClassInstance
}

trait ReactClassInit extends js.Object {
  val render: js.ThisFunction0[js.Dynamic, js.Any]
}



@JSExport
object ReactTodo {
  //Some helpers I use.
  val * = js.Dynamic.literal

  @JSExport
  def main() {
    helloJonT()
  }


  //Ideal Typed Example
  def helloJonT() {
    val init = *(render = new js.ThisFunction0[js.Dynamic, js.Any] {
      override def apply(thisArg: js.Dynamic): js.Any = {
        React.DOM.div(null, "Hello ", thisArg.props.name)
      }
    }).asInstanceOf[ReactClassInit]
    val HelloMessage = React.createClass(init)
    React.renderComponent(HelloMessage(*(name = "Jon").asInstanceOf[js.Object]), document.getElementById("content"))
  }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently, the recommended approach is very close to what you are doing, except that the use of `js.Dynamic.literal` should be encapsulated in the companion object of your trait (`ReactClassInit` in your case). You can provide a type-safe `apply` method in that companion object like this:

```
trait ReactClassInit extends js.Object {
  val render: js.ThisFunction0[js.Dynamic, js.Any]
}
object ReactClassInit {
  def apply(render: js.ThisFunction0[js.Dynamic, js.Any]): ReactClassInit = {
    js.Dynamic.literal(
      render = render
    ).asInstanceOf[ReactClassInit]
  }
}
```

which you can then use with:

```
val init = ReactClassInit(render = { (thisArg: js.Dynamic) =>
  React.DOM.div(null, "Hello ", thisArg.props.name)
})
```

Of course this is still globally unsafe. But there is only one point in your code where you use a cast, and more importantly it is *close to* the definition of the type. So it is more likely that if you update one, you will update the other.

I know this is not a completely satisfactory solution. But so far in our design of Scala.js we have not yet found a really good solution to this problem.

Two side notes:

1) I **strongly advise against** using `new js.ThisFunctionN { def apply }`! It is an accident that this notation works at all. Simply use a lambda like I showed in my example. If the target type is typed as a `js.ThisFunctionN` already (like in my code), it'll work just like that. If, as was the case in your code, the target type is `js.Any` (or `Any`), you'll need to ascribe your lambda with `: js.ThisFunction` (without digit) to make sure that the compiler treats it as a this-function and not a (non-this-)function, but that's all. To make it clearer, here is how it would have looked with your code:

```
val init = *(render = { (thisArg: js.Dynamic) =>
  React.DOM.div(null, "Hello ", thisArg.props.name)
}: js.ThisFunction).asInstanceOf[ReactClassInit]
```

2) You probably want your function to be typed as returning `Any` (or `_`) instead of `js.Any`:

```
trait ReactClassInit extends js.Object {
  val render: js.ThisFunction0[js.Dynamic, Any]
}
```

Typically when you use `js.Any` in the result type of `js.(This)Function`, you mean *any value*, not *any JS value*. And Scala's type inference works best with `Any` in that location.