# Scala JS: Call a Javascript function on an element

Tags: javascript, scala, scala.js

I have the following problem. I would like to use https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it/ in my project. However I am not sure how I am supposed to implement the following example given on the github page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#myTags").tagit();
});
</script>

<ul id="myTags">
 <!-- Existing list items will be pre-added to the tags -->
 <li>Tag1</li>
 <li>Tag2</li>
</ul>
```

So far I am able to manipulate the object:

```
val document = js.Dynamic.global.document
document.getElementById("myTags").innerHTML = "Test"
```

This works! `Test` is being rendered.

When I call `tagit()` instead I am being told that `tagit is not a function`.

```
val document = js.Dynamic.global.document
document.getElementById("myTags").tagit()
```

When I do the "same" call with the chrome java script console everything works fine:

```
$("#myTags").tagit();
```

Can someone explain what I am doing wrong? Thank you in advance!

**EDIT**

It is not a problem of tag-it or jquery not being loaded. Again chrome console works. It is also not a loading issue. Even by clicking a button after everything is loaded for a 100% it doesn't work.

**EDIT**

Added my partial build defintion so everybody can see that the dependencies are correct:

```
.jsSettings(
      jsDependencies ++= Seq(
        "org.webjars" % "bootswatch-yeti" % "3.3.5" / "js/bootstrap.js" minified "js/bootstrap.min.js" dependsOn "jquery.js",
        "org.webjars" % "jquery-ui" % "1.11.4" / "jquery-ui.js" minified "jquery-ui.min.js" dependsOn "jquery.js",
        "org.webjars" % "tag-it" % "2.0" / "js/tag-it.js" dependsOn "jquery.js" dependsOn "jquery-ui.js"
      ),
      libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
        "io.github.widok" %%% "widok" % "0.2.2" exclude ("org.webjars", "bootstrap"),
        "be.doeraene" %%% "scalajs-jquery" % "0.8.0",
        "com.lihaoyi" %%% "scalatags" % "0.4.6",
        "org.webjars" % "bootswatch-yeti" % "3.3.5",
        "org.webjars" % "font-awesome" % "4.4.0",
        "org.webjars" % "jquery-ui-themes" % "1.11.4"
      ),
      persistLauncher := true
    )
```

Comment: two problem, one) you may not add tag-it js to your website two) tag-it added before jquery.

Comment: @Omidam81 both not the case. I even installed a button to test to be sure everything is loaded. It doesn't work. Chrome console works, button doesn't.

Comment: please check the answer. thank you,

Comment: your code is correct, but i think the problem is come form order that you add script(with src) tags.

Comment: @Omidam81 no that can't happen with scala js. I updated my question. As you can see I am already telling the compiler that tag-it depends on jquery and jquery-ui. Once this is done everything is handled for you. There can't be a mistake there.

Comment: i'm not familiar with Scala.js, but i think you forget to add jQuery in your definition.

Comment: yes, i familar with such syntax,  it used in require.js also, but i think you must add jquery in your first part also(jsDependencies).

Comment: @Omidam81 no I do not. Jquery is already added by `libraryDependencies += "be.doeraene" %%% "scalajs-jquery" % "0.8.0"` otherwise the compiler would throw an error when it does not find `jquery`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem, initially, is that

```
// Scala.js code
document.getElementById("myTags").tagit()
```

is *not* "the same" as

```
// JavaScript code
$("#myTags").tagit();
```

Instead, it is the same as, guess what?

```
// JavaScript code
document.getElementById("myTags").tagit();
```

which is not valid because `tagit()` is not a method of `HTMLElement` returned by `getElementById`. `tagit()` is a (pimped) method of `JQuery` objects returned by the `$` function.

You can obtain the `$` function in a dynamically typed way using:

```
// Scala.js code
val $ = js.Dynamic.global.$
```

and then you can write *the same* as the jQuery invocation by writing this:

```
// Scala.js code
$("#myTags").tagit()
```

The solution found is essentially similar, because the `jQuery` object is equivalent as `$`. But then the returned element is a `JQuery` object, which *statically* does not have a `tagit()` method, which is why you needed to cast it to `js.Dynamic`.

Another way would be to type the `tagit()` method pimp using this:

```
// Scala.js code
@js.native
trait JQueryTagIt extends js.Object {
  def tagit(): Unit = js.native
}

implicit def tagItExtensions(jq: JQuery): JQueryTagIt =
  jq.asInstanceOf[JQueryTagIt]
```

With that, you can more simply do:

```
// Scala.js code
jQuery("#myTags").tagit()
```

and it will be statically typechecked.

Comment: Thank you very much! Great explanation. One thing I still do not understand is how I should pass options. e.g. `tagit({tagLimit: 1})`.

Comment: With the dynamically typed version, use `js.Dynamic.literal(tagLimit = 1)`. For the statically typed version, see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26638171/how-do-i-create-options-objects-in-scala-js

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myTags").tagit();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://bitar.tk/tag-it.min.js"></script>

<ul id="myTags">
 <!-- Existing list items will be pre-added to the tags -->
 <li>Tag1</li>
 <li>Tag2</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Have you seen that I am using Scala JS? I am building a SPA (Single Page Application). One defines the scala dependencies using a sbt build defintion. I updated my awnser so that everybody can see my deps.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution which works. It uses jQuery bindings for Scala JS. By building your own static bindings is the correct way I guess.

```
jQuery("#myTags").asInstanceOf[js.Dynamic].tagit()
```

**UPDATE**

Please see the following post (https://stackoverflow.com/a/32994303/1029251) since this approach is simply wrong considering what scala.js stands for. My solution is not typesafe!

Comment: This approach always works, but it's not recommended if you can avoid it, because it takes you out of strongly-typed land, and strong typing is kind of the point of Scala.js.  So this sort of thing is usually treated as a last resort.

Comment: @JustinduCoeur I agree 100%. I posted this before sjrd awnsered. I will edit the post.