# scalajs js.native object throws "is not a constructor"

Tags: scala.js

I have the following class

```
@js.native
class Foo extends js.Object {
  var bar: String = js.native

}
```

And in my JSApp I have

```
object TutorialApp extends JSApp {

  @JSExport
  val bar = new Foo()
}
```

When I run I get $g.Foo is not a constructor. Following [the scalajs doc](https://www.scala-js.org/doc/interoperability/facade-types.html) I can not get what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: That's a native facade. Are you sure you have included the JS library that declares `Foo` as a top-level constructor?

Comment: @sjrd ah no. I want to write a facade for chartjs 2 but they have new Chart("canvasId", {...}). How would you instantiate the second arguments anonymous object? Since the lib mutates this object case classes do not work.

Comment: Ok, I found the solution here on SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26638171/how-do-i-create-options-objects-in-scala-js I was just confused of the usage of js.native