# how to define facade for a method that emits events in ScalaJS

Tags: facade, scala.js

I'm writing scalajs facade for  [pouchdb](http://pouchdb.com/api.html)

code : https://gist.github.com/chandu0101/62013de47bf5ee4d2412

how to define facade for API name [changes](http://pouchdb.com/api.html#changes) which emits events and return a cancel method ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Defining Scala.js facade types is all about giving static types to a JavaScript API. Usually the documentation of the JavaScript *does* mention types, which can therefore be translated into a formal definition pretty easily.

In this case, the `changes` methods returns an [`EventEmitter`](http://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_class_events_eventemitter), which is the first thing you need. Let us define this type, and in particular its `on` method:

```
class EventEmitter extends js.Object {
  def on(event: String, listener: js.Function): this.type = js.native
  ...
}
```

We have to be very imprecise for the type of `listener`, unfortunately, because the actual type will very much depend on the event string, and the particular uses of that emitter. In general, we cannot predict anything at this point.

The documentation of `EventEmitter` doesn't mention a `cancel()` method, which is a bit weird since apparently that method can be called on the emitter returned by `changes`. So we'll define a subtype for the particular emitter returned by `changes`:

```
trait ChangesEventEmitter extends EventEmitter {
  def cancel(): Unit = js.native
}
```

We can also take advantage of this specialized trait to enable a more precise type of listener for particular events. In this case, let us do it for the `change` event:

```
object ChangesEventEmitter {
  implicit class ChangesEventEmitterEvents(
      val self: ChangesEventEmitter) extends AnyVal {
    def onChange(listener: js.Function1[js.Dynamic, Any]): self.type =
      self.on("change", listener)
  }
}
```

Finally, you need a type for the `options` parameter of the `db.changes` method. The type itself is usually a trait with many immutable fields:

```
trait DBChangesOptions extends js.Object {
  val include_docs: js.UndefOr[Boolean] = js.native
  val limit: js.UndefOr[Int] = js.native
  ...
}
```

To *construct* an instance of such a type, you may either go with an `apply` method in the companion object with default arguments (see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23663059/what-is-the-suggested-way-to-instantiate-a-js-object-for-api-wrappers)), or you can create a `Builder`-like class for it.

And now, we can finally declare the `changes` method itself:

```
def changes(options: DBChangesOptions = ???): ChangesEventEmitter = js.native
```

Comment: thank you very much , regarding  options trait and companion objects i am already doing that for other methods you can check in gist :)

Comment: could you please explain me how companion object ChangesEventEmitter  works ... ?

Comment: It works just like any other [implicit class](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/implicit-classes.html). There's nothing Scala.js-specific in there.